# AWS ec2: ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I have aws linux ubuntu ec2 t2.micro instance with django application deployed, recently I installed boto3 and django-storages on my ec2 instance and created s3 bucket, after which I was unable to makemigrations on my django project as it kept saying

"-bash: fork: Cannot allocate memory issue in EC2 "

after which I stopped and started ec2 server and then I am unable to access ec2 via command line or ftp, even with new public ip. it says

"ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer"

ftp connects sometimes but then few moments later it again says

"Error:         Connection reset by peer
Error:          Could not connect to server"

need some help here that if issue is due to my storage or usage limit  or for some other reason?

Thanks,
Bilal

Comment: can you add -vv option and share the results ? `ssh -vv user@host`

Comment: well with -vvv it says
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file Karibpay-ubuntu-key.pem type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file Karibpay-ubuntu-key.pem-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer

Comment: It looks like your machine is running out of memory based on the first error you show.  I would try to create a machine with a larger amount of memory as a test and see how much memory your application is taking.

Comment: ya, it connects sometimes both on cli and via ftp and I can run commands or download/upload files  and after some time it start to say again that connection reset by peer, any way I can know how much memory I have used and what is left? and how can I update it?